# ubuntu php sqlite database access error

Tags: php, ubuntu, sqlite

I tested, changed permissions, reinstalled apache2, reconfigured apache2 to public_html, studied the web for solutions for almost a day now. Banging my head to the wall at this point.

This is what I have:

1. medical01 - sqlite3 database, with the table persons in it, table filled with 101 records
2. the php script:

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   echo '1';
   $location = 'sqlite:/medical01';
   echo '2';
       $dbhandler = new PDO($location);
   echo '3';
   ```
3. permissions:
   -> folder medical that contains the following files:

   ```
   drwxr-sr-x 2 gabriel www-data 4096 Nov  5 16:55 medical

   -rwxr-sr-x 1 gabriel www-data  1634 Nov  5 11:49 index.php
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 gabriel www-data 11264 Nov  5 10:51 medical01
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 gabriel www-data   386 Nov  5 13:32 script01.php
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 gabriel www-data   163 Nov  5 16:55 script02.php
   ```

As you can see, everything is in one folder. This is what I get when running the script02 file in firefox:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in /home/gabriel/public_html/medical/script02.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/gabriel/public_html/medical/script02.php(7): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/medical...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/gabriel/public_html/medical/script02.php on line 7
```

Any help would be appreciated, as at this point I am desperate.

Comment: The code you are attempting to run would help.

Comment: I *think* I remember something about SQLite also wanting to create some temporary files in the same directory as the database-file.  Do the permissions allow that?

Comment: I managed to make the php code show up... still not formatted as code though...

Comment: Not sure about the temp files... how do I check for those permissions?

Comment: You could move the database-file into its own directory with dangerously-open permissions.

Comment: Done that too (all permissions granted), still the same error. I dug the web for answers and tried everything I could find. Why does it have to be so difficult to access a database!??! Done it in the past, under Windows, with MySQL, but I need sqlite3 now!